# Traducción de “put this/it down to experience”

Tags: traducción, expresiones, coloquialismos

¿Cómo traducirías **put this**/**it down to experience**, en el contexto de pasar una humillación, una molestia o un mal rato para conseguir algo difícil que no se entrega en bandeja y no necesariamente la persona aprenderá la lección o se arrepentirá porque le gusta o lo necesita, por lo tanto hay muchas posibilidades de recaer, pero de alguna forma va a quedar en su retina, guardado en sus registros y va a aprender de eso y si es que se repite tratará de enfocar las cosas de diferente forma o de inclinar la balanza a su favor y probablemente no volverá a ser tan descuidado. Una traducción literal sería "poner en la cuenta de la experiencia".
Intentos:

- Sentar un precedente.
- Servir de precedente.

```
sentar un precedente (LOCUCIÓN)
1. Hacer una cosa que cree la obligación de actuar de la misma manera ante un caso posterior parecido o que sirva de ejemplo o referencia para tratar casos posteriores.
2. Quedar [una acción] como ejemplo, norma o referencia para tratar casos posteriores parecidos.
```

También pregunto por traducciones que sean coloquiales, propias de cada país.

Comment: animo a poner algún punto en el párrafo inicial. Corremos el riesgo que alguien lo lea en voz alta y fallezca :P

Comment: Chileno muy coloquial... **una vez pa' los vivos**

Comment: Algo como eso buscaba, algo muy coloquial o que diera justo en el clavo, si hubieras creado tu propia respuesta, esa hubiera calificado como correcta. Y no hay algún argentino, mexicano, cubano, puertorriqueño, paraguayo, gallego o colombiano, etc qué a haga su aporte? Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como diría mi abuelita:

¡Que te sirva de ejemplo!

También funciona:

¡Que te sirva de experiencia!

Comment: Y una abuela más severa diría: "Que te sirva de escarmiento".